# How does HDD firmware espionage software work

Tags: hard-drive, virus

NSA's most recent addition to modern espionage is some type of HDD firmware, as found by [Kaspersky](http://www.kaspersky.com/about/news/virus/2015/equation-group-the-crown-creator-of-cyber-espionage) and later reported by [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/02/16/us-usa-cyberspying-idUSKBN0LK1QV20150216), [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/02/how-hackers-could-attack-hard-drives-to-create-a-pervasive-backdoor/) and others. But I don't get how it functions:

- Does it do more than one thing?
- Or does it only infect the boot sector when activated?
- Or does it infect .exe files?
- Or does it collect information which is later transmitted by one of the forementioned methods?
- Or something else entirely?
- How is it activated?

**Edit:** Wired just published [an article](http://www.wired.com/2015/02/nsa-firmware-hacking/) with some more facts and some more guesses. It seems either the EquationDrug or GrayFish bootkit downloads malcious HDD firmware from some server, then flashes it to HDD, leaving some extra space for storing encryption keys and the like.

The firmware *might* leave some unused space on disk available for data collected by EquationDrug och GrayFish.

The stored encryption key (or password or whathaveyou) on the HDD ROM could possibly be extracted manually/physically if the computer is taken through customs.

Sound a bit far-fetched? I guess that if the resources are unlimited and the hackers are exceptional and willing. I still would like to know if someone understood more on exactly what the firmware does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article you provided (reading as I write this):

> The ROM chip that contains the firmware includes a small amount of storage that goes unused. If the ROM chip is 2 megabytes, the firmware might take up just 1.5 megabytes, leaving half a megabyte of unused space that can be employed for hiding data the attackers want to steal.

One way to do this, which is probably not super-complicated (but still complicated) is to flash a firmware that recognizes additional commands that aren't standard ATA commands.  These commands can store data in a separate area from the disk itself, but the OS (since it never issues non-standard commands and you can at least send non-standard commands via  custom driver, if not through the standard drivers) won't touch it or know about it, and it would be extremely difficult for a program to detect it.

I'm sure hacked firmware returns the same exact version strings as normal firmware, so verifying through that method is not possible.   I don't think you can download the currently executing firmware to verify it - you can flash a new firmware though.

So malware could then store some data in a disk, separate from the data that's "officially" supposed to go the drive's platter/NAND.  This could be used to merely "mark" a disk for detection later, or maybe copy some data from memory (like Truecrypt keys in RAM) to it.

A much harder way would be for the firmware to detect when specific files are being read and return modified data instead.  This is extremely complicated (you'd have to know about the filesystem on the disk, fully support it in the limited space of the disk's firmware storage, and be aware of a whole lot of OS-imposed changes that could screw the illusion up).

EDIT: After further reading it looks like it does something like hide a partition table that is "unlocked" with a custom command?  Since the MBR partition table is at a known location (sector 0), this isn't too hard.